# MSYS2: make command not showing anything and running for too long

Tags: windows, makefile, msys2, pgbadger

I am trying to install [pgBadger](https://github.com/darold/pgbadger) for windows, so I installed MSYS2 and perl (needed for pgBadger). Now, when I run `make` in the MSYS2 bash window, it shows nothing, and the `make` command just get stuck for hours (no error or any log).

I got to know about MSYS2 for installing pgBadger from [here](https://github.com/darold/pgbadger/issues/480)

Does the make command takes time in the MSYS2 window OR is there any other problem here ?

Comment: That is not normal.  If I had to guess I'd say that something is waiting for you to type some input.  I recommend running `make -d` and see what the debugging output shows.

Comment: It's stuck at Reading makefile 'Makefile'....

Comment: I assume you already generated the Makefile from Makefile.PL in this Perl project.  I'm not familiar much with Windows but I still suspect it's waiting for input.  If you hit ENTER a few times does it move forward?  You may need to debug the makefile, by looking at what it does (look especially for any variable assignments using `:=` and with the `$(shell ...)` function on the right-hand side).  You can try asking for help from the pgBadger folks although they may not be Windows users either.

Comment: I tried to press Enter multiple times, but nothing, I even entered some "test" string, but it says "test" is not recognised as an internal or external command. For the variables, there is nothing like `:=` but I found this `USE_MARKDOWN=$(shell which pod2markdown)`, but I am not sure what it means.

Comment: Aha!!! _test is not recognized as an internal or external command_ is very interesting.  That message is from Windows command.com shell.  This means that make has invoked a shell and the shell is waiting for your input.  If you type *exit* does it continue on?  Clearly there's something odd going on here related to Windows and/or your installation but again, I'm not a Windows person so I don't think I can help much.

Comment: What does `which test` say? If you run it from MSYS2 shell.

Comment: Actually I was doing a mistake here. I installed Strwaberry Perl and ran the command `perl Makefile.pl` from it, then I used make from MSYS2, which was not working. So I used `gmake` by strawberry perl and it ran without any errors. I was mixing different things together.